# Find the open eclipse dialog programmatically

Tags: eclipse

It is possible to find an active page/editor in eclipse. How can we programmatically get hold of the instance of the open modal dialog in eclipse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no corresponding interface in Eclipse to access any current model dialog. The best approximation is `Display.getActiveShell()`, which will return the shell that hosts the active dialog if one exists.

[Dialogs are implemented by having their own event loop, so it can be rather difficult to run your own code...]

***EDIT***: Based on your comment below, here is a small snippet I use constantly to test for the presence of specific preference pages. I guess this can be used used as the starting point for your own test... Note the use of `Display.timerExec(...)`.

```
public void test(String pageId) {
    try {
        final IWorkbench workbench = PlatformUI.getWorkbench();
        final Shell[] shells = workbench.getDisplay().getShells();
        final ICommandService cs = (ICommandService) workbench.getService(ICommandService.class);
        final ParameterizedCommand command = cs.deserialize("org.eclipse.ui.window.preferences(preferencePageId="
                + pageId + ")");
        assertNotNull(command);

        final IHandlerService hs = (IHandlerService) workbench.getService(IHandlerService.class);
        // Have to use timerExec to get the runnable executed after the dialog is shown
        workbench.getDisplay().timerExec(2000, new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                assertEquals(shells.length + 1, workbench.getDisplay().getShells().length);
                final Shell lastShell = findLastShell(workbench.getDisplay().getShells(), shells);
                assertNotNull(lastShell);
                final Object data = lastShell.getData();
                assertNotNull(data);
                assertTrue(data instanceof PreferenceDialog);
                lastShell.close();

                assertEquals(shells.length, workbench.getDisplay().getShells().length);
            }

            private Shell findLastShell(Shell[] currentShells, Shell[] oldShells) {
                CheckNext: for (final Shell cs : currentShells) {
                    for (final Shell os : oldShells) {
                        if (os == cs) {
                            continue CheckNext;
                        }
                    }
                    return cs;
                }
                return null;
            }
        });
        hs.executeCommand(command, null);
    } catch (final Exception ex) {
        fail(ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: I had tried this but having the shell really doesn't serve the purpose. I mean with the active editor you can do loads of stuff like access its input or programatically call save. But with just the shell I wouldn't be able to even try out the ok/cancel buttons programatically.

Comment: What exactly do you want to do with the dialog?

Comment: I need this as a part of automation testing. I need to trigger very simple operations (ok click and cancel pressed)